# How to convert Array of any of elements in to dataframe in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Array like `Array[(Any, Any, Any)]`. For example:

```
l1 =  [(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(x,y,z)]
```

I want to convert it to a Dataframe as:

```
c1    c2    c3
a     b     c
d     e     f
x     y     z
```

I tried to convert the existing dataframe to a list:

```
val l1= test_df.select("c1","c2","c3").rdd.map(x => 
(x(0),x(1),x(2))).collect()
println (lst) 
val c = Seq(l1).toDF("c1","c2","c3") 
c.show()
```

But it is throwing this error:

```
xception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what is the type of `l1 = [(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(x,y,z)] `?

Comment: its a  Array[(Any, Any, Any)] type

Comment: try to make a `String` of the elements - like `x(0).toString..`

Comment: After converting to toString getting this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match

Answer (score 0):

In Pyspark:

```
l1 =  [('a','b','c'),('d','e','f'),('x','y','z')]
sdf=spark.createDataFrame(l1)
sdf.show()
```

Comment: I want to implement it is Scala